# How to daily download and merge a csv file and update on Google sheets?

Tags: database-design, optimization, automation

Disclaimer: I’m not sure if this question goes on here. I’ve trying to solve this issue for quite a while and I don’t think there is another way other than using a python script.

I need to solve this problem:

I want to download every early morning a csv file from my work- it requires to access a site, go thru login (no captcha) and then select the proper fields to download a csv file.

The second step is to merge this file which should contain the previous day data within a large database that should be kept running. I want to send this data to a Google spreadsheet file, so that we can easily control it later on.

My current option is to have the secretary daily download it and update the spreadsheet. This is a terrible solution.

My second idea is to study a bit further python to create an automation that would retrieve the data and update the spreadsheet.

Is there some sort of tool that would allow me to do it? I believe this must be a recurrent issue, and somewhat of a simple question… but after browsing the web for a solution I could only find web scrappers building tips for python.

I want to apologize beforehand for my very simple
Question, I’m aware that you guys are discussing really advanced subjects and I am a complete scrub with data analysis, and finding good solutions is often challenging.

Thanks for your comprehension and collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure out the exact same thing. I've automated my csv download every morning with make (formally integromat) and have it place the newest version of the csv into a Google drive folder. I can access the daily csv file from Google sheets.

I planned to make another gsheet that would read this csv and format it, but I'm thinking utilizing an actual database would be more appropriate since there are thousands of records and data points. I'm honestly probably going to end up using Excel and power query since that is what I'm most familiar with until I come up with something more robust.

Comment: Your first step seems to be a solution to my problem. Could you explain it a bit further? As per your data formatting- if you already have the csv files uploaded, have you tried the import functions of Google sheets? I believe that import range and query functions could possibly solve your data wrangling problem.

Comment: That depends on the verification you need to make the http requests. In my case I have [make](https://MAKE.com) do a "http basic auth request" with my client_credentials to get a new access_token. The I have to pass that access_token to pull the response which is formatted as a csv. Finally a google drive update file step. [scrshot](https://imgur.com/e8M1uIS)

I am downloading a domo dataset so I had good docs to reference. Copying the cURL requests, and viewing the headers, payload, responses on the network tab of cromes inspector was helpful in figuring the flow for auth + the data request